# ES6 Class prototypes - type resolution

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, es6-class

Here's the use case

Ive extended the Array class:

```
class ExtendedArray extends Array {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.test = 10;
  }

  testTwo() {
  }
}
```

Now i have some methods where i want to map my `ExtendedArray` instance and return another instance of `ExtendedArray` which works out of the box.

However in other situations i want to map over the `ExtendedArray` but return an actual `Array` instance and not my `ExtendedArray`. In this situation i thought i could walk up the `__proto__` chain and call `.constructor`.

This is when i noticed some odd behavior which i didn't expect.

Based on the class above i would have expected a hierarchy like this

```
/*
  ExtendedArray
    test: 10
    __proto__: Object
        testTwo: () {}
      __proto__: Array
        forEach
        ...
        __proto__: Object
            ...
*/
```

However i get one like this:

```
/*
  ExtendedArray
    test: 10
    __proto__: Array -- Different
        constructor: class ExtendedArray
        testTwo: () {}
      __proto__: Array(0) -- Different
        constructor: f Array()
        forEach
        ...
        __proto__: Object
            ...
*/
```

Can anyone explain what the difference between `Array` and `Array(0)` is in the prototypes type. Also why is the first prototype an instance of Array when its constructor is the `ExtendedArray` class and when its created based on the methods in the class body definition. I would have expected that to ether be an `Object` or `ExtendedArray` in type?

Any help understanding this behavior would be great.

I've attempted to research this and found information explaining where the different class fields and methods go in the resulting object, but not how the types of prototype objects are resolved.

Comment: Instead of relying on the console to dissect the object, write your own tests. The ExtendedArray constructor will have its own prototype object, and the prototype of *that* object will be the Array prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "types" shown in the debugger are pretty meaningless. They're just trying to be helpful on instances, but usually cause confusion on prototype objects. They are also different between browsers, and often change between devtools versions.

All those values are simply objects, and their structure and prototype chain is exactly what you are expecting.

> What is the difference between `Array` and `Array(0)`?

The `Array.prototype` object has a `.length = 0` property. Your `ExtendedArray.prototype` has not.

> Why is the first prototype an instance of `Array` when its constructor is the `ExtendedArray` class. I would have expected that to ether be an `Object` or `ExtendedArray` in type?

It's not an `ExtendedArray` *instance* - it doesn't inherit from `ExtendedArray.prototype` (because it *is* `ExtendedArray.prototype`). It's just an object like `{constructor: ExtendedArray}`.

It does however inherit from `Array.prototype`, so that's what is shown as the "type".

Comment: The click moment was right here `It's not an ExtendedArray instance - it doesn't inherit from ExtendedArray.prototype (because it is ExtendedArray.prototype). It's just an object like {constructor: ExtendedArray}.` I was forgetting the detail that an object is just and object but also only an instance of something else if it appears in the tested object prototype chain. thanks!